# How to Parse the data from .property file from Jenkins using Index

Tags: bash, powershell, shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Property file in Jenkins lets call it Something.txt

and Something.txt contains

```
A_B_C
D_E_F
```

and i have used below shell to read the file and Execute my Automation

```
file="/var/lib/jenkins/components.txt"

if [ -f "$file" ]
        then
             echo "$file found."
             Websites="$(awk -F '_' '{print $1}' $file | paste -d, -s)"
             Profiles="$(awk -F '_' '{print $2}' $file | paste -d, -s)"
             Component="$(awk -F '_' '{print $3}' $file | paste -d, -s)"

                for i in $(echo $Websites | sed "s/,/ /g"); do 
                    for j in $(echo $Profiles | sed "s/,/ /g"); do
                        for k in $(echo $Component| sed "s/,/ /g"); do


mvn clean verify -D "cucumber.options=--tags @"${j} -D surefire.suiteXmlFiles=./XMLScripts/${i}.${k}.testng.xml ||true
done
                    done
                done
```

but what is happening is My Job is running as

```
A-B-C & A-B-F & D-B-C & B-E-F
```

but the expected result is `A-B-C & D-E-F` how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

[Don't read lines with `for`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

file="/var/lib/jenkins/components.txt"

if [[ -f "$file" ]]; then
  while IFS=_ read -r website profile component; do 
    printf '%s %s %s\n' "$website" "$profile" "$component"
  done < "$file"
fi
```

In your case you can do

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

file="/var/lib/jenkins/components.txt"

if [[ -f "$file" ]]; then
  while IFS=_ read -r website profile component; do 
    echo mvn clean verify -D cucumber.options=--tags @"$website" -D "surefire.suiteXmlFiles=./XMLScripts/$profile.$component.testng.xml" ||true
  done < "$file"
fi
```

Remove the echo if you're satisfied with the result.